# How to find my pip?

Tags: debian, python, pip

Yesterday I installed the pip with

```
python get-pip.py
```

and it can be regular used.
Now it shows this.

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

so I try to use python get-pip.py to install it again.

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/python-2.7.11/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But what about the PATH?

Then I **try** to add all of involved path into PATH.

```
/usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/pip:/usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/python2.7:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/python
```

None of those work.

I saw some similar questions which told me to find the correct path.

```
# which python

# /usr/bin/python

which pip

...(nothing)
```

The python's installed path is /usr/local/python-2.7.11.
I used `ln -s /usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/python  /usr/bin/python` before install pip.

My system is Debian7.

Comment: I think this is not a good question because I'm a newbie of Linux.The pip words since I changed the PATH /usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/python to /usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin. Maybe it also inspares you. Thank you Jeff for helping me to edit the mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

When you install `pip` with `python getpip.py`, the `pip` command gets installed next to the python binary. In your case that is `/usr/local/2.7.11/bin`. As your python executable is found through its link, that directory is not used for any other commands.

Your PATH should have paths, i.e. directories, not full file names.
The directory to include in your PATH is  `/usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin`.
If you do that you can get rid of the link.

You can also setup a link:

```
ln -s /usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/pip  /usr/bin/pip
```

As python is found because of the link, and pip installed (but not found), you can also invoke pip by doing:

```
python -m pip
```

and you can make that into an alias if you don't want to add an extra link:

```
alias pip='/usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/python -m pip'
```

Comment: No module named pip error

Comment: yes that is what you get before you install pip with `python getpip.py`, thanks for sharing.

Comment: this worked for me
alias pip='/usr/local/python-2.7.11/bin/python -m pip'